# What does the {{#_}} ... {{/_}} block mean in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Here is an example:

```
        {{#_}}<strong class="point-submitter">
          {{#if submitter.avatar_url }}
            <img src="{{ submitter.avatar_url }}" class="avatar" />
          {{^}}
            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/images/user-50.png" class="avatar" />
          {{/if}}
          {{#if submitter.name }}
            {{ submitter.name }}
          {{^}}
            {{#if submitter_name }}
              {{ submitter_name }}
            {{^}}
              {{ anonymous_name }}
            {{/if}}
          {{/if}}
        </strong> {{ action_text }} this {{ place_type_label location_type}}

        {{#if region}}
          in {{ region }}
        {{/if}}{{/_}}
```

taken from here:
https://github.com/openplans/shareabouts/blob/master/src/sa_web/jstemplates/place-detail.html#L6

What difference is made by using the `{{#_}} ... {{/_}}`  block? I did not find much on the [Handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/), and searching for terms like `#_ handlebars block underscore` was not very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not part of regular Handlebars or Mustache - it's part of the Django-jstemplate library for doing Internationalization.

https://django-jstemplate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#internationalization-i18n

Answer (score 2):

As said in [project architecture](https://github.com/openplans/shareabouts/blob/master/doc/ARCHITECTURE.md)

This is mustache templates, not handlebars.
Documentation of mustache.js can be found [here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

`{{#_}} ... {{/_}}` - is a section which behaviour depends on `_` variable value.

As Nick pointed - the `_` variable contains i18n setting